# Is a quotient of $k[x,y]$, where $k$ is a field, a finitly generated module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noetherian, finitely-generated

i'm trying to prove the claim in the title, my argument is:

$k$ is a field so it's Noetherian, hence so is $k[x,y]$ by the Hilbert basis theorem, hence $k[x,y]$ is a Noetherian $k$-module, and a quotient of it is also finitely generated, as every submodule of a Noetherian module is finitely generated.

However it appears to me that, in the same argument, $k[x]$ and $k[x,y]$ are finitely generated $k$-modules as well because they are submodules of $k[x,y]$, which is clearly absurd. Could you tell me in which step did I make a mistake? Thanks!

Comment: $k[x,y]\cong k[x,y]/\{0\}$ is not finitely generated as a $k$-module (only as a $k[x,y]$-module). Consider for example the indpendant elements $1,x,x^2,x^3,\dots$. Basicially: You confused $k$-modules and $k[x,y]$-modules

Comment: $k[x,y]$ is a Noetherian ring, meaning it is Noetherian as $k[x,y]$-module. This is not the same as being Noetherian as a $k$-module.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I think I get it now.